# How to keep the same "INSERT INTO" statements in my code when adding a new column in my database with the "nullable" property and a default value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's consider a "User" MySQL table with 2 columns:

- Auto increment id
- Full name

```
CREATE TABLE `user` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `fullname` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (NULL, 'John Smith');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (NULL, 'James Miller');
```

Everywhere I add a user in my application, I'm having this code:

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (NULL, <name to insert>);
```

Now if I add a 'is_admin' boolean with 0 as default value, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD COLUMN `is_admin` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

If I run my insert query with `VALUES (NULL, <name to insert>)`, I expect MySQL to understand that I want new users to have is_admin set to 0, but it doesn't work:

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I thought it was because of the 'NOT NULL' flag so I changed the 'ADD COLUMN' statement from 'NOT NULL' to 'NULL':

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD COLUMN `is_admin` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Now it's pretty obvious how I want it to behave. I said the default value should be 0 and I didn't even set it to mandatory. But I still get the same error.

I just have to update all my `INSERT INTO` user occurences to:

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (NULL, <name to insert>, 0);
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (NULL, <name to insert>, default);
```

In this example it looks like it's not a big deal, but on a big application with tens of INSERT statements, it's a big deal because at each version, you must modify all insert statements for all altered tables, and if you miss a single one, then it doesn't work anymore.

I worked many years with Oracle and maybe I'm wrong but I thought I remembered Oracle was using default values when not provided.

Is there any way to do the same with MySQL?

Comment: Provide us with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE user` and `SELECT @@sql_mode` then we know better what the problem might be.. But pretty sure @GordonLinoff 's answer is already correct here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes his answer is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always list the columns when doing an insert.  So:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, fullname)
    VALUES (NULL, 'John Smith');
```

That, in turn, is overkill.  Just do:

```
INSERT INTO user (fullname)
    VALUES ('John Smith');
```

This will set `is_admin` (and any other columns) to their default values.